# is it possible to make desktop alert when request for technician is issued, using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have developed online ticketing system

i need an alert pop up message on my desktop whenever a user request for technician

heres my jquery code for adding a request

function add_rec() {

```
        var Technician = document.getElementById("txtTech").value;
        var Name = document.getElementById("txtCaller").value;
        var Office = document.getElementById("txtOffice").value;
        //var Request = document.getElementById("Request").value;
        var Pending = document.getElementById('Pending').checked;
        var Finished = document.getElementById('Finished').checked;

        if (Technician == '' || Name == '' || Office == '') {

            alert('Please check your entries and try again.')

        } else {
            if (Pending == false && Finished == false) {
                alert('Please check your entries and try again.')
            } else {
                action("Function2.asmx/add_rec?Technician='" + Technician + "'&Name='" + Name + "'&Office='" + Office + "'&Request=''&Pending='" + Pending + "'&Finished='" + Finished + "'");

                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    //call your display function here to update the displayed data
                    get_TicketStats();
                    get_rec();
                    clear_rec();
                }, 100);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: how is this client javascript connected to _your_ desktop?

Comment: its not connected on my desktop, its actually connected to my other code at c# for inserting data on my database. so when user insert data (the request) i need the browser to show notifications or popups.

Comment: You could poll a webservice/database to check if any new tickets came since your last check of the webservice/database. This would disconnect your notification application from your website, but since the one doesn't have anything to do with the other, that would be an acceptable compromise (not to mention that you could then also program other applications to generate messages on changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a web page (reliably) pop up a notification on the user's desktop.
Browser settings often block popups, or force them to open in new tabs, instead. There's nothing you can do about these settings.

You could use JavaScript's native `alert()` function. In some browsers, it forces that tab to the foreground, if the browser isn't minified.

Comment: is there any other way to use pop up or any notification?

Comment: There are plenty of JS libraries out there to display notifications / popups, but they all have these limitations.

Comment: is it a pop from desktop or browser only?